# Convert xml dictionary to csv with bash

Tags: xml, bash, csv, data-conversion

I have a var $ENTRIES

```
ENTRIES="<entry key="key-one">value</entry> <entry key="key-two">value/two</entry>"
```

Which needs to be converted to csv:

```
convertToCSV() {
    # Do stuff with $ENTRIES
} >> dict.csv
```

Resulting in:

```
cat dict.csv
key-one,value
key-two,value/two
```

How would we extract the key and values from $ENTRIES?
Would say we would need some kind of sed command?
Where we take the key between:

```
key=" and ">
```

And take the value between:

```
> and </entry>
```

And somehow loop through all the entries in $ENTRIES...

Answer (score 1):

try following once and let me know if this helps you. Once you are happy with results you could re-direct this value to .csv output file then.

***Solution 1st:***

```
echo "$ENTRIES" | awk -v RS=" " '{sub(/.*=/,"");sub(/<.*/,"");sub(/>/,",");if($0){print}}'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** Adding one more solution here too.

```
ENTRIES="<entry key=\"key-one\">value</entry> <entry key=\"key-two\">value/two</entry>"
echo "$ENTRIES" | awk -v RS='<entry key=|</entry>' 'NF{sub(/>/,",");gsub(/\"/,"");print}'
key-one,value
key-two,value/two
```

Comment: Super! However it results the key with quotes:
"key-one",value
"key-two",value/two

Comment: So second would be:
    echo "$ENTRIES" | awk -v RS='<entry key="|</entry>' 'NF{sub(/">/,",");print}'
Could you edit both solutions, then I can accept it as a answer. (:

Comment: I have escaped " in your variable to let it be in the variable's value, now see my edit now and let me know if this helps you.

Comment: My proposal in my last comment already takes out the " in the csv, escaping the " in the $ENTRIES wouldn't be a solution for me.

Comment: how you are saving $ENTRIES variable? Because to create any variable in shell you need to only give variable name and while printing it you need to provide $variable_name. So when you put variable_name="values...." in that if any " comes you need to escape it, so that only I escaped it, let me know on same.

Comment: Ah yeah I see I had a typo, $ENTRIES is the input as is.

Comment: Then we have to escape " inside the variable's value for sure to escape it's special meaning from this, code I have given is working perfectly for me, let me know if you have any queries on same.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use XPath with `xmlstarlet`...

```
ENTRIES='<entry key="key-one">value</entry> <entry key="key-two">value/two</entry>'

echo "<doc>$ENTRIES</doc>" | \
    xmlstarlet sel -t \
    -m "/doc/entry" \
    -v "concat(@key,',',normalize-space())" \
    -n \
    > dict.csv
```

Notes:

- I needed to wrap the `$ENTRIES` variable with another element (`doc`) to make the XML well-formed.
- I needed to change the `ENTRIES` variable by removing the `$` and changing the outer quotes to apostrophes.